# Invalid policy role due to malformed Json? AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am following this tutorial: https://bernhardwenzel.com/articles/using-clojure-with-aws-lambda/

the json for the policy is as shown:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

but when I run

```
aws iam create-role \
--role-name basic_lambda_role \
--assume-role-policy-document fileb://resources/trust_relationship.json
```

I get

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json
```

Not sure what the problem is here.
I tried fixing the file path or removing the b but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your policy is fine.

I think the error comes from `fileb` which should be used for [binary data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html), such as `UserData` in ec2.

The following form should be used (use `file`, not `fileb`):

```
aws iam create-role \
   --role-name basic_lambda_role \
   --assume-role-policy-document file://resources/trust_relationship.json
```

Comment: I tried running that form but it gives me a no such file or directory error. Should I be running the form in the base directory? My trust_relationship.json file is in my resources directory.

Comment: @Anonymous You have to double check where is your file. Maybe it different folder or has different name.

Comment: This is my directory structure: ```.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── doc
│   └── intro.md
├── LICENSE
├── project.clj
├── README.md
├── resources
│   └── trust-relationship.json
```

Comment: @Anonymous Try from the resource folder. The `file` is correct. You can verify that by checking the example from [aws-doc](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/create-role.html#examples) for `create-role` command.

Comment: Okay, I was able to hit the file by removing // after file: but the console is still giving me the same error: An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json

Comment: @Anonymous I run the command with your policy. It works. There must be something else happening. Maybe your file is incorrectly encoded, or has some strange white characters?

Comment: I made a new directory with the singular json file in it and used the path to that file to run the form and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Anonymous Glad it worked out. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.